# "Живые квартиры" — ошибка или нет?

Tags: грамотная-речь, реклама

Реклама: "Живые квартиры". Будет ли это речевой ошибкой (имеется в виду слово "живые")?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь нет речевой ошибки при условии, **если из текста рекламы понятна условность названия "живые квартиры".**

1) Этот "термин"  применяется в современных проектах  **для описания многофункционального пространства** квартир, которое,  **подобно живой природе**, может  **трансформироваться,**  в том числе  меняться в соответствии **со временем года.** **Именно поэтому такие квартиры  условно называют "живыми."**

2) Другой вариант  — это система "умный дом"(умный — значит, "живой"). Вот одно из описаний такого дома: https://www.artlebedev.ru/city-block/

В каждой квартире — горизонтальная система отопления, оборудованная теплосчетчиком. Это значит, что расход тепла рассчитывается для каждой квартиры отдельно.

В общественных местах устанавливаются датчики движения — например, свет зажигается, только когда кто-то выходит в холл. В зданиях используется система «умный дом», то есть освещением и входной дверью жители управляют прямо из квартиры.

Специальная система собирает дождевую и «серую» воду (из стоков кухни и ванной) — она используется для подогрева в теплосистемах, полива растений на крыше и в садах и повторного применения. Сады на крыше удерживают воду, обеспечивают дополнительную термоизоляцию и делают город зеленее. При желании на крыше устанавливаются еще и солнечные батареи.

3) **Существуют и другие концепции "живых квартир",** когда в интерьер помещения вписаны **уголки живой зелени**, например:

"Между окнами сделали каркасные панели вертикального озеленения. Это был самый сложный и интересный процесс. Ведь необходимо было тщательно продумать все детали по установлению технологии **полного цикла самообслуживания данной растительности".** https://interiorsmall.ru/sovremennaya-kvartira-studiya-s-zelonymi-stenami/

Answer (score 1):

"Живые районы" в рекламе встречаются часто, а вот "живые квартиры" , возможно, и ошибка, если имеется в виду квартира в "живом районе"от застройщика А 101 в Москве, например. Живыми, вероятно, называются экологически чистые районы, что к квартире отнести нельзя. Значит, здесь лексическая ошибка - подмена понятий.